# Synaptics touchpad Issue after OS reinstall

Tags: drivers, touchpad, synaptics

recently I have been facing with issues for Nvidia drivers and eventually I decided to clean install Ubuntu 21.04. which indeed solved the issue. However, now my touchpad is not working at all. At this point I am quite desperate and feel like I have tried everything. But I am not a highly experienced Linux user so there is a chance that I did not do something correctly.

Previously I was running Ubuntu 19.04. I have tried to boot into this version from USB drive but now it does not work even there. Is there any use of reinstalling OS again if it does not even work when booting from USB? My machine is Dell Vostro 14-5459 and it has Synaptics touchpad. It is surely not a hardware issue since I can use touchpad in the Dell diagnostics menu.

The output of `xinput list` is this:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Genius Optical Mouse                      id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ DELL Wireless hotkeys
```

I tried installing and reinstalling the `xserver-xorg-input-libinput` and `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` drivers over and over. Even tried to find the drivers in the Synaptics Package Manager App.

Upon boot my computer displays repeatedly message:

```
ic2_hid i2c-SYNA2393:00: failed to reset device.
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, at this point I have no idea what else to try.
Thanks

Comment: Open mouse and touchpad settings, and check if the touchpad is disabled there.

Comment: Hello, unfortunately the settings for Mouse&Touchpad display only options for mouse, as if the touchpad wasn't recognized.